# specify two files at once on the linux command line

Tags: linux

I have two files that I need to add to git:

```
modified:   source_files/aws_environments/aws_account_numbers_no_spectrum.txt
modified:   source_files/aws_environments/aws_environments_no_spectrum.txt
```

I tried to add both files to git using this command:

```
git add source_files/aws_environments/aws_{accountnumbers,environments}_no_spectrum.txt
```

But when I run that command I get this result back:

```
fatal: pathspec 'source_files/aws_environments/aws_accountnumbers_no_spectrum.txt' did not match any files
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I specify both files to git correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is called `aws_account_numbers_no_spectrum.txt`, with an underscore between `account` and `numbers`. Your syntax is correct, but the underscore is missing.

Correct command is:

```
git add source_files/aws_environments/aws_{account_numbers,environments}_no_spectrum.txt
```